# R CMD check NOTEs on ggplot, subset, etc

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using ggplot or subset, a `R CMD check` command on my package generates the following notes:

```
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
foo: no visible binding for global variable ‘bar’
```

for a mock function such as

```
foo <- function(dataframe) { subset(dataframe,bar>10) }
```

That `R CMD check` section is useful when forgetting about the usage of global variables in a package. Therfore I'd like to have it clean.

Is there a possibility to let R know of the special nature of ggplot/subset?

Comment: For the record, that had happened to me too on a simple (`with(foo, subset(...))` or similar, so it has nothing to do with `ggplot2` per se. I had meant to report it on r-devel but then I must have gotten distracted).  Seems like a bug in `tools` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the reason that this is a `NOTE` not a `WARNING` or `ERROR` - there's currently no automated way to detect the use of non-standard evaluation in a function.